# Spark coalescing on the number of objects in each partition

Tags: apache-spark

We are starting to experiment with spark on our team.
After we do reduce job in Spark, we would like to write the result to S3, however we would like to avoid collecting the spark result. 
For now, we are writing the files to Spark forEachPartition of the RDD, however this resulted in a lot of small files. We would like to be able to aggregate the data into a couple files partitioned by the number of objects written to the file.
So for example, our total data is 1M objects (this is constant), we would like to produce 400K objects file, and our current partition produce around 20k objects file (this varies a lot for each job). Ideally we want to produce 3 files, each containing 400k, 400k and 200k instead of 50 files of 20K objects

Does anyone have a good suggestion?

My thought process is to let each partition handle which index it should write it to by assuming that each partition will roughy produce the same number of objects. 
So for example, partition 0 will write to the first file, while partition 21 will write to the second file since it will assume that the starting index for the object is 20000 * 21 = 42000, which is bigger than the file size. 
The partition 41 will write to the third file, since it is bigger than 2 * file size limit. 
This will not always result on the perfect 400k file size limit though, more of an approximation.

I understand that there is coalescing, but as I understand it coalesce is to reduce the number of partition based on the number of partition wanted. What I want is to coalesce the data based on the number of objects in each partition, is there a good way to do it?

Comment: Why not store it to parquet or ORC? You could use `.repartition` instead of `.coalesce` to determine the exact number of files you'd want.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on storing it to ORC or parquet?

Comment: Also, I can determine the exact number of files, however, I don't really care how much files that is being generated. I care more about how big the file is that is being generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to re-partition the files into three partitions; the data will be split approximately 333k records per partition. The partition will be approximate, it will not be exactly 333,333 per partition. I do not know of a way to get the 400k/400k/200k partition you want.

If you have a DataFrame `df', you can repartition into n partitions as

```
df.repartition(n)
```

Since you want a maximum number or records per partition, I would recommend this (you don't specify Scala or pyspark, so I'm going with Scala; you can do the same in pyspark) :

```
val maxRecordsPerPartition = ???
val numPartitions = (df.count() / maxRecordsPerPartition).toInt + 1
df
    .repartition(numPartitions)
    .write
    .format('json')
    .save('/path/file_name.json')
```

This will guarantee your partitions are less than maxRecordsPerPartition.

Comment: Yes, this is what we ended up doing actually

Answer (score 0):

We have decided to just go with the number of files being generated and just making sure that each files contain less than 1 million line items